# Some browser tab headers start with the first tag, but some don't

Tags: support, tags, title

**When you have SE tabs open in a browser (in this case, Chrome), some have one of the tags (usually the leftmost one) followed buy the question name.  LIke this:**

[image]

**But others seem to just have the question title, with no tag preceding it.  Like this:**

[image]

The discrepancy is not a function of beta vs. live sites; I found both examples within one type.  It seems like leading with the title (and no tag) is better for two reasons:

1. the tag selection seems arbitrary when there are multiple tags
2. The tag reduces the likelihood that you can tell which tab you need - someone who focuses on a tag could have multiple tabs open with the same tag, but not with the same heading.

Answer (score 8):

If the tag is already mentioned in the title, it is not added again. On all sites (except Arqade) the most-used tag is added in front of the title, unless it is already present there. On Arqade the two most-used tags are added.

Adding the tag is important on certain sites where it is custom to leave out important information from the title and just put it in the tag. On Stackoverflow the programming language is often only present in a tag, not the title, but it is arguable the most important piece of information about the question. The same goes for Arqade (Gaming.SE).

Answer (score 7):

If the tag is already included in the title, then it doesn't include it again. That title already has "bike computer" in the title, so including "bike-computer" at the beginning isn't useful. It then goes to the second most popular tag, which doesn't exist, so not tag is included.